# Custom legend order ggbiplot, built off ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggbiplot

I have created a PCA plot in using the `ggbiplot()` function, form the `ggbiplot` package, which is built on top of `ggplot2`. Here is an analogous, reproducible example:

```
library(ggbiplot)
data(wine)
wine.pca <- prcomp(wine, scale. = TRUE)
print(ggbiplot(wine.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, groups = wine.class, ellipse = TRUE, circle = TRUE))
```

[image]
So far so good. I want to change the legend order to grginolino, barbera, barolo (rather than barolo, grignolino, barbera as it is now). The names are stored in the environmental factor variable `wine.class`.

Apologies for such a simple question, but I cannot find a straight forward answer from the `ggplot2` help that generalizes to this case.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. Is your `wine` data coming from the package Factominer ? I so use `data(wine, package = "FactoMineR")`. Then the data needs preprocessing before PCA --> numeric data is needed.

Comment: @cbo apologies, I forgot to include the library call to `ggbiplot`, which has the `wine` dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reorder `wine.class` levels; look below:

```r
library(ggbiplot)

data(wine, package = "ggbiplot")
wine.pca <- prcomp(wine, scale. = TRUE)
wine.class.reorder <-  factor(wine.class, levels = c("grignolino", "barbera", "barolo"))

ggbiplot(wine.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, groups = wine.class.reorder, 
                   ellipse = TRUE, circle = TRUE)
```

[image]